# Dagger2 disable AndroidInjection.inject(this); for instrumentation test

Tags: android, testing, dagger-2

With the latest Dagger2 we can inject dependencies through the following code:

```
public class BaseActivity extends LifecycleActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AndroidInjection.inject(this);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Other activities that require DI inherit from this BaseClass. 
For my instrumentation tests, I don't want to use Dagger, I can just mock the objects.

My setup for the instrumentation test (I'm currently testing LoginActivity, which extends BaseActivity) is not special and as follows:

TestRunner:

```
public class LivefeedTestRunner extends AndroidJUnitRunner{
    @Override
    public Application newApplication(ClassLoader cl, String className, Context context)
            throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException {
        return super.newApplication(cl, TestApp.class.getName(), context);
    }
}
```

TestApp:

```
public class TestApp extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }
}
```

The problem is that running the instrumentation test results in an error caused by:

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.example.kimgysen.livefeed_v002.TestApp does not implement dagger.android.HasActivityInjector
at dagger.android.AndroidInjection.inject(AndroidInjection.java:48)
at com.example.kimgysen.livefeed_v002.ui.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:12)
at com.example.kimgysen.livefeed_v002.ui.login.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:32)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
at android.support.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:624)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
... 9 more

Which points to the following line:

```
public class BaseActivity extends LifecycleActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AndroidInjection.inject(this); // <-- this line 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Any idea how I can easily bypass this? 
In my app itself, I implement `dagger.android.HasActivityInjector`, but I don't need it for my instrumentation test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the problem by creating a fake activityInjector as suggested in the following post:
https://github.com/google/dagger/blob/master/javatests/dagger/android/AndroidInjectionTest.java#L60

(equivalent for fakeActivityInjector)

```
public class TestApp extends Application implements HasActivityInjector {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public AndroidInjector<Activity> activityInjector() {
        return fakeActivityInjector("injected by app");
    }

    public static class InjectableActivity extends Activity {
        String tag;
    }

    private static AndroidInjector<Activity> fakeActivityInjector(String tag) {
        return instance -> {
            if (instance instanceof InjectableActivity) {
                ((InjectableActivity) instance).tag = tag;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative solution in the [android-architecture-components](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/) samples on Github.

They [inject](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/di/AppInjector.java) the activities trough [ActivityLifecycleCallbacks](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html). For instrumented tests they use a [TestApp](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/androidTest/java/com/android/example/github/TestApp.java) that does not register ActivityLifecycleCallbacks so it injects nothing.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48101811/1552622.