# Disable Dagger injection in tests

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, dagger-2

I have the following LoginFragment that uses Dagger to inject its fields:

```
class LoginFragment : DaggerFragment() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory)
                .get(LoginViewModel::class.java)
    }
```

I also have a corresponding test that mocks the LoginViewModel according to the documentation from Google: "You can create the fragment and provide it a mock ViewModel."

```
@MediumTest
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class LoginFragmentTest {

    @Mock
    private lateinit var viewModel: LoginViewModel

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        loginFragment = LoginFragment()

        loginFragment.viewModelFactory = createMockViewModelFactory(viewModel)

        activityRule.activity.setFragment(loginFragment)
    }
}
```

The problem is that when the `onAttached` method of the fragment is invoked, Dagger overrides the `viewModelFactory` with its own object, thus replacing my mock.

How can I prevent Dagger from overriding my mock object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the [android-architecture-components](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/) samples on Github Google have an interesting solution.

They [inject](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/di/AppInjector.java) the activities trough [ActivityLifecycleCallbacks](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html). For instrumented tests they use a [TestApp](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/androidTest/java/com/android/example/github/TestApp.java) that does not register ActivityLifecycleCallbacks so it injects nothing.

Just like in your example the `ViewModel.Factory` is package private so in the test you can assign it yourself.

For `Fragments` there is [FragmentManager.FragmentLifecycleCallbacks](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.FragmentLifecycleCallbacks.html) class which can be used. Instead of the `Fragment` injecting itself in `onActivityCreated` your production activity injects the `Fragment` using `FragmentLifecycleCallbacks`. You can create a testing activity which does not inject the fragment and you can create a mock factory yourself.

Comment: Thank you, sounds interesting. I will give it a try.

Comment: It worked perfectly, my only concern is that the injection happens in the `onActivityCreated()` callback, which might be too late, since it's recommended to call `AndroidInjection.inject()` immediately in `onCreate()`, before calling `super.onCreate()` (check the "When to inject" section here: https://google.github.io/dagger/android.html).

Comment: @makovkastar I suggested `onActivityCreated` because that's where you were injecting the fragment. Take a look at [onFragmentPreCreated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.FragmentLifecycleCallbacks.html#onFragmentPreCreated(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager, android.support.v4.app.Fragment, android.os.Bundle))

Comment: Sorry, my comment was a bit confusing. I was talking about injecting members of the activity itself. For the fragment I used the `onFragmentPreAttached` callback, so that's no problem. But if we want to inject members of an activity, `onActivityCreated` might be too late.

Comment: @makovkastar the documentation for `ActivityLifecycleCallbacks` is not clear on when exactly is the callback triggered. But it is used in an official Google sample. Unless you run into any problem it should work.

Comment: Is there a solution using DaggerFragment without switching to their implementations (back applying a custom interface like `Injectable` to all the Fragment)? I didn't find nothing about this way of testing...